# Can we fetch details of load balancer from instance ID in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to fetch details of the load balancer that are associated with some instance of AWS. Can we do that?

Vice versa is possible using `describe-load-balancers` [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html]. I want to fetch load balancer details from instance-Ids

Answer (score 1):

You can get the instance-ids that an ELB has in service using the DescribeLoadBalancers API Call. Here is the CLI documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html

However, it is not possible to find out what ELB an instance is being served by without writing a custom script.

You will need to write a script that does a DescribeLoadBalancers API call. You will then need to filter through the results and check if your instance id is present in the "Instances" field of the result.

Comment: Thanks ! I also came to the same conclusion. I'll google some more and if nothing comes up then i'll go with custom script.

Comment: The AWS API doesn't provide this functionality. I don't think you'll have any other option but to write a custom script :)

Comment: Note also that it's possible to attach an instance to more than one ELB.  The correlation is not restricted to 1:1.